# changing the referer in post request in python

Tags: python, post, header, referer

I'm trying to change the referer in post request in the code below but it seems not to work.

```
request = requests.post("https://someurl.com/", data=result,
                                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                                     "Referer":'https://someotheuerl.com/',
                                                     })
```

have no idea what to do for fixing this problem

Comment: Do you get an error? Please post an error or some more code or something?

Comment: no errors just referer won't change at all this way

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide error messsage or unexpected output you received.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
request = requests.post("https://someurl.com/", data=result, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', "referer":'https://someotheuerl.com/'})
```

Comment: It seems like your answer is the same as what I've already written!

Comment: I switched it from Referer to referer, see if it works @zahrajm